# Which module to use for controlling the Keyboard?

Tags: python, python-3.x, keyboard, pynput

Which Python module should i use to control the Keyboard of my Computer?

The code below should launch the Notepad with "Whatever you wanna type" on it but is showing that there is no module named `Pynput`

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller  
import time 
x = Controller()

x.press(windows)

x.release(windows)

x.type("notepad")

x.press(enter)

time.sleep(1)

x.type("Whatever you wanna type")
```

Comment: If you do: `pip install pynput`, will work. notice that `windows` isn't declared anywhere in your code

Answer (score 0):

You can use `keyboard` module, you can install by `pip3 install keyboard`

Here is a similar way to do the exact task using `keyboard` module:

```
import keyboard
import time

keyboard.send("windows")
time.sleep(0.5)
keyboard.write("notepad")
keyboard.send("enter")
time.sleep(1)
keyboard.write("Whatever you wanna type")
```

Note that `send()` method is equivalent to `press()` followed by `release()`